# Looping through form fields with different names

Tags: javascript, loops, field

So I have a form with a bunch of Text fields.  Some of the fields are related and I need to loop through them and add up the numbers in the value field.

The fields are all named differently so I can tell them apart so I'm not sure how to look through them.

Can I set them all to the same ID or same something to then do the loop based on the shared property?  I'd rather not have to manually go through them all but can do that if I have to.

I guess maybe if all the fields are part of a form array I can figure out where the fields I want start and stop and loop them that way?  hmmm

Comment: IDs must be unique, but you can give them all the same class attribute and select them by their class.  if you use a library like jquery, selecting by classnames can be very easy.

Comment: So the text inputs contain numbers, and you want to loop through and add those numbers up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them all a class name. Eg. `class="inputs"` .
Add them to an array, then loop through with a `for` loop.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs");
for(i =0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
{
  // whatever you want to do now.
}
```

Comment: OK.  So I can just add a class="whatever" to each Input field that I want to be looped through?  That sounds like a perfect solution.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: Indeed! I use this in pretty much everything! You're very welcome, and good luck!

Comment: I want to know why this was down voted. I mean sure probably not the best to have 10+ elements with a class of "inputs" but, is it really worth downvoting? I mean his code will work nonetheless.

Comment: This should not have been downvoted. Since getElementByName is a useful method that's depricated in HTML5, getElementByClassName is a great alternative -- especially for iterating through grouped inputs like radio buttons and check boxes.

Answer (score 6):

Native JavaScript is much simpler. A form node is an array of all its named controls, as well as an object with attributes.

The named controls are described in [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-name) and in the [HTML 4.01 one](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls).

The W3C solution is quite elegant.

```
var form = document.querySelectorAll( 'form' )[0];
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    console.log( form[i] );
    total += parseInt( form[i].value );
}
```

There's no need for libraries. The only downside is that `fieldset`s in the form are iterated through as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution... which *should* be the best solution, not just the one that the question author ended up using.

Comment: Yes it should, and always using jQuery is something that is making start to hate javascript.

Comment: Downvoted because this will also return [fieldsets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset), which have no `.value`.

Comment: upvoted @DanDascalescu

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked before, although the question was worded differently.

Check here for several solutions, including the one already given by tinkerBot

[How to parse input[] values and put them into a Javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210720/how-to-parse-input-values-and-put-them-into-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write semantic HTML, you should group the related `<input>` fields into a [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset), add an id to it, then loop through them with:

```
var total = 0;
var inputs = document.querySelector('yourFieldsetId').querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  total += Number(inputs[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want all the inputs for a given form, you can use jquery to easily get all the inputs within a form and iterate the values out:

http://jsfiddle.net/3TyZA/

```
$("#form1").find("input").each(function( index ) {
     console.log($(this).val()); // the value of each input
});
```

Comment: [No need to use jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27628482/1269037).